# re-defining an existing function as method of a class

Tags: python, class, methods

I am learning to use classes. 
I want to create a class with several methods and attributes. 
In my case, some of the methods might be functions that I have written elsewhere in the code.

Is it a good practice to re-define the functions as methods of the class like in the following example?

```
def f(x,b):
    return b*x

class Class1:
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.b=8.
    def f(self,x):
        return f(x,self.b) 


instance1=Class1(5)
print instance1.f(7.)
```

The code returns what it should, but is this the right way to do it or perhaps it is redundant or it might lead to troubles for larger codes?

What is the right way to define methods using function written elsewhere?

Comment: There's no conflict between regular functions and class methods.

Comment: This would depend on the context. Using other functions in method calls in fine. Why make it a method though? At least in this example, `self` is never used,

Comment: A better example would be if it were something like `def f(self): return f(self.somevar)`

Comment: If it doesn't need access to `self` at all, then don't make it a method in the first place.

Comment: I struggle understanding the use of `self`. I see it everywhere when I watch tutorials about classes but I still don't get when it is needed and when it is not. For example, if I get it right, in this little code it was superfluous ?

Comment: It's used when the class is maintaining some state. `self` is the reference to access that state. If there is no state, you usually don't use a class in the first place.

Comment: Methods mostly just functions associated with instances of a class, and `self` is that instance (and is automatically passed to methods as their first argument).

Comment: Nice, so it is a good habit to write the functions that I will need in a separate place and then just use them inside the class or re-define them as methods? 
The alternative would be to just define everything directly inside the class, but I'd end up with a huge file and I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: @3sm1r Some things are better as functions; others are better as methods. There's really no notion of rewriting one as the other. If you have a group of functions that *all* take a similar argument, *that* is a sign that they could be rewritten as a group of methods of a single class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Functions...

Consider the following group of functions:

```
def stack_push(stack, value):
    stack.append(value)

def stack_is_empty(stack):
    return len(stack) == 0

def stack_pop(stack):
    return stack.pop()
```

Together, they implement a stack in terms of a built-in list. As long as you don't interact with the list directly, the *only* thing they allow is adding values to one end, removing values from the same end, and testing if the stack is empty:

```
>>> s = []
>>> stack_push(s, 3)
>>> stack_push(s, 5)
>>> stack_push(s, 10)
>>> if not stack_is_empty(s): stack_pop(s)
10
>>> if not stack_is_empty(s): stack_pop(s)
5
>>> if not stack_is_empty(s): stack_pop(s)
3
>>> if not stack_is_empty(s): stack_pop(s)
>>>
```

---

## ... vs. Methods

Notice that each function takes the same argument: a list being treated as a stack. This is an indication that we can instead write a *class* the represents a stack, so that we don't need to maintain a `list` that could potentially be (mis)used outside of these three functions. It also guarantees that we start with an empty list for our new stack.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def push(self, value):
        self.data.append(value)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.data) == 0

    def pop(self):
        return self.data.pop()
```

Now, we don't work with a `list` that supports all sorts of  non-stack operations like indexing, iteration, and mutation at the beginning or middle of the list: we can *only* push, pop, and test for emptiness.

```
>>> s = Stack()
```

Things like `s[3]`, `s.insert(2, 9)`, etc are not allowed.

(Note that we aren't strictly prevented from using `s.data` directly, but it's considered bad practice to do so unless the class says it is OK to do so in its documentation. In this case, we do *not* allow that.)

We use these methods much like we used the `stack_*` functions.

```
>>> s.push(3)
>>> s.push(5)
>>> s.push(10)
>>> if not s.is_empty(): s.pop()
10
>>> if not s.is_empty(): s.pop()
5
>>> if not s.is_empty(): s.pop()
3
>>> if not s.is_empty(): s.pop()
>>>
```

The difference is, we cannot "accidentally" use other list methods, because `Stack` does not expose them.

```
>>> s.insert(3, 9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

---

Finally, note that we don't write our original `stack_*` functions and use them in the definition of the `Stack` class: there is no need; we just define the methods explicitly inside the `class` statement.

```
# No.
class Stack:
    def push(self, value):
        stack_push(self.data, value)
```

We also don't continue to use the `stack_*` functions on an instance of `Stack`.

```
#  No no no!
>>> stack_is_empty(s.data)
```

Comment: I see.  How would you do if you had written a function that is suited for your class in some other file,  so that you have to import the file and the function comes with it?  Is it fair in this case to use `def f(self, x) : return f(x)`?

Comment: In what way is `f` related to your class, if the wrapper method doesn't use `self`?

Comment: I need to apply several functions to the same matrix.  Since I didn't want all the functions to be written in the same file in which the class relative to the matrix is defined, I thought that I could just define them somewhere else and re-define them more synthetically inside the class.

Comment: Without a more concrete example, I'm just going to say "no, don't do this", because the functions you are describing in your question don't show any relationship to the class, and so there's no reason to define methods that wrap the function.

Comment: I made a more concrete example in the edit. The function is given a parameter that is internal with respect to the class. However, I don't want to define `f` only inside the class, because the function might be general enough that I could use it for other purposes as well.

Comment: That's fine, because the function `f` has nothing to with an instance of the class, but the method uses it to do something that *is* related to the class. The fact that you are reusing the same name makes them seem more related than they really are.